# Symfony LiipImagineBundle: filters not working for big images

Tags: php, symfony, wamp, liipimaginebundle

I am currently developing the possibility for some users to upload images on a backend. Those images are supposed to be rendered on a mobile app later.

I am in an early stage of development, I want to resize images that any users are uploading to the server. But for now I am working locally with Wamp, works fine when I want to apply filter to images under approximately 1000X1000. Then bigger images are not filtered, the original image is stored indeed, but the filtered one supposed to go to web/media/cache isn't.

I can't seem to find a solution for now, I have to say I am a beginner in Symfony development. I am starting to think this is something related to cache with Wamp.

Here is my configuration in config.yml for more precision:

```
liip_imagine:
resolvers:
    default:
        web_path: ~
filter_sets:
    my_small:
        quality: 100
        filters:
            thumbnail: { size: [275, 100], mode: outbound }
    my_big:
        quality: 100
        filters:
            thumbnail: { size: [550, 550], mode: inset}
```

Has anyone ever experienced the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

try raising the memory limit in php.ini. It works for all heavy php code, not only drupal
https://drupal.org/node/29268

Answer (score 1):

I was ignoring Symfony's profiler. Now I have more information:

post_max_size_message -> The uploaded file was too large. Please try to upload a smaller file.

Comment: Actually that don't seem to be the reason, since the original image is uploaded, but not the filtered images. Those last one don't go through the form.

Answer (score 0):

LiipImagineBundle I think is mainly for filtering images, not uploading.  If you are going to upload and mainly want the filtered images viewed, you many want to consider saving the filtered images permanently so that the filters do not need to run every time the cache is cleared.

I use the [OneupUploaderBundle](https://github.com/1up-lab/OneupUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) for uploading images, and use php's built in functions for resizing and applying simple filters, and then save the copies - a resized one with certain dimensions and a thumbnail.  This way the user can upload large files, but the ones served on the webpages are optimized and can easily be cached since they are static and do not need to be created again.

Another benefit is that the user can upload multiple images at one time, plus it supports multiple frontends which allow it to be nicely styled with the look of your app.

Comment: Allright I'll give this one a try, fixing the cache has nothing to do with it. I definitely have to find an alternative, thanks for this one, I'll see if I can implement that.